# Antiword returns empty array

Tags: php, apache, parsing

I have this script,

```
<?php
exec('/usr/local/bin/antiword /var/www/html/rezyme_2015.doc', $output);
var_dump($output);
?>
```

but in browser I see:

```
array (size=0)
empty
```

I have in `/usr/bin/antiword` and I copy to `/usr/local/bin/antiword`. If I run in console:

```
php antiword.php
```

Output is

```
  [0] =>
  string(0) ""
  [1] =>
  string(52) "hello"
  [2] =>
  string(0) ""
```

In one forum, I saw the exact problem reported. The person that has this problem says that he solved this problem. Here is the quotation:

"Yes, it turned out to be the accessibility of the map files - they weren't world readable, once I changed permissions, it worked great. Thanks all"

However, I did not unnderstand how he solved the problem and how also I can reach and allow those map files of antiword.

And I found:
Maybe the user apache or www-data or nobody or whatever your webuser is 
called, has no permissions to execute it?

You can simply check this by:
1) sudo su www-data (or whatever etc.etc see above)
2) call the script as you do in your exec() command

Or you blocked exec() in PHP.ini.

I not found in PHP.ini in /etc/php5/apache2/ and /etc/php5/cli/  this blocked exec() or exec()
And I run in my terminal:

```
     sudo su www-data 
     This account is currently not available.
```

My question, why in my browser this script not correctly work:

```
    array (size=0)
    empty
```

When I get chmod 777 -R for file.doc then I have return array, but how do right ?

and what I need for fix this problem, step-by-step, whats create, whats change, help please.

Comment: I check for my problem like that:
`$content = shell_exec('/usr/bin/antiword -m cp1251.txt '.'chmod o+r /var/www/aog-profile/web/'.$path['url']);`
But I have big array:
`dump($content[1], $content[2], $content[99], $content[100], $content[101]);exit;`
`DeveloperProfileController.php on line 181:
":"
DeveloperProfileController.php on line 181:
"y"
DeveloperProfileController.php on line 181:
"m"
DeveloperProfileController.php on line 181:
"e"`
And what type field in the database must be if I want set all arrays?

Comment: And I check problem, I used doctrine and my field

`   /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $textCv;`
shell_exec return longtext, exec return array

Comment: I used symfony 2.6 and for cyrilic I use 

`$content = shell_exec('/usr/bin/antiword -m UTF-8.txt '.'chmod o+r /var/www/aog-profile/web/'.$path['url']);`

work great, I set in DB and I see cyrilic in DB :)